# Design pattern or best practise for the **business layer** (or say **data model**) of an application?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, architecture, business-logic

In the MVCs, MVPs, MVVMs and the likes there are clear distinct reponsibilities for each of the layers. The MVX architecture is often stated to be enforced by the framework that is used (windowing libs like Qt, web frameworks like Django...), at least this is what these frameorks claim forcefully.

I have often found that in order for these MVX architectures to be fully enforced you need a great deal of extra architecturing behind the model layer provided by frameworks Qt, wxWidgets, React, Django, Rails... e.g. the **model layer** of Qt is a thin layer that plays well with the **view layer** of Qt but what is key for these MVX patterns to work is having an **underlying business data model layer** that:

1. Contains the data
2. Keeps the dependency between the different pieces of data (and makes the relevant updates when an input changes)
3. That tells the model layer when to send signals

Are there any patterns, libraries, well guided approaches, best practise that help coding the business layer behind the model?